# Give me some recommendation about JBoss and MySQL using Openshift Tech

Tags: mysql, jboss, openshift

I've created my first application using Openshift Tech. It's a Java Web Application running on a JBoss at Openshift and uses MySQL 5.5 as its database. And I have to deploy by it using the war file (I don't know how to do it the normal way).

So anyone can tell me: Should I create a local database or use online database? And is there another way to deploy my Java app not using the war file?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check out the OpenShift Developer Center (https://developers.openshift.com), specifically this link (https://developers.openshift.com/en/jbossas-overview.html) about using jboss.  Make sure you read all of the sections, specifically the Deployment Options, and the Datasources links.  If you are interested in just being able to do a "git push" to deploy your code, you should create a new jboss application on OpenShift, and do a "git clone" of the code and check out how it's setup, it is using the Maven project structure, which is pretty common.